# How can I create customized Domain-specific Processes with User task functionality in jbpm6?

Tags: jbpm

I want to wrap this [process](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1q14qb57ijgore4/01.jpg) into a customized component

i've read the [Domain-specific Processes Document](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.0.1/userguide/jBPMDomainSpecificProcesses.html), but i didn't find a way to add a ActorId on Domain-specific process

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any property to a domain specific work item handler. You have to add the properties to a WID file and include it in the conf to get the property names in the editor. However, if you want to use a human task, there is no need to create a domain specific handler.